# How to send multiple HTTP requests in NGRX Effects properly?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I've written the Effect below for a single HTTP request:
(payload of **getRequestObj** is an object)

```
@Effect()
   indexDoc$ = this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType<IndexDocuments>(myActionTypes2.IndexDoc),
      mergeMapTo(this.store.select(getRequestObj).pipe(
         take(1)
      )),
      mergeMap((request: any) => this.myService.indexDoc(request).pipe(
         map((response: any[]) => new IndexSuccess(response)),
         catchError(error => of(new IndexFail(error)))
      ))
   );
```

What I want is, feeding the Effect with an array, and send an HTTP request for each item in the array. What I tried:
(payload of **getRequestArray** is an array of objects)

```
@Effect()
   indexDocs$ = this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType<indexDocs>(myActionTypes1.IndexDocs),
      concatMapTo(this.store.select(getRequestsArray)),
      concatMap((request: any[]) => {
         return zip(...request.map(item => {
            return this.myService.indexDocs(item).pipe(
               map(response => {
                  return this.store.dispatch(new IndexSuccess(response))
               }),
               catchError(error => {
                  return Observable.of(this.store.dispatch(new IndexFail(error)));
               })
            )
         }))
      })
```

What happens is, all of the requests return 412 Precondition Failed error. How do I make it work properly?

Comment: If it makes the requests but server returns `412` then the problem is probably somewhere else and not in the RxJS chain. Check request headers.

Comment: It seems that the request headers somehow get changed when multiple requests are sent from a single Effect. @martin